# Why are all proper ring varieties trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-groups

$
\newcommand{\A}{\Bbb A}
\newcommand{\Set}{\mathsf{Set}}
\newcommand{\Sch}{\mathsf{Sch}}
$
Define a ring variety to be a variety$^{[1]}$ $X$ over a field $k$, such that the functor of points 
$$\Sch_k \to \Set, 
\quad S \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}_k(S, X)$$
factors through the forgetful functor from the category of rings to $\sf Set$.

> The exercise 1.4 [here](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/elenalavanda/BMoonen.pdf#page=19) claims that the only ring variety which is proper over $k$ is the point $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$. My question is to understand why.

(Exercise 1 [here](http://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/AbelianVar/Assignment1.pdf) assumes $k$ to be algebraically closed).

Notice that this not true without the completeness hypothesis. 
Typically, $\A^n_k : S \mapsto O_S(S)^n = \Gamma(S, O_S)^n$ is an *affine* ring variety. 
When $n=r^2$, we can also endow $\A^{r^2}_k : S \mapsto M_r(O_S(S))$ with a structure of non-commutative ring variety. But I don't know what happens if the variety is proper.

Related: [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87512/).

---

$^{[1]}$
i.e. a separated and integral scheme of finite type.

Comment: A vague idea : it seems that "ring varieties" are varieties with a ring structure. Forgetting the multiplication, this implies that we have a proper commutative algebraic group which is automatically a torus $(k^*)^r$, so you just need to check those are not ring varieties.

Comment: @Art : right, I meant tori like abelian varieties, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a proper ring variety over a field $k$.  Note first that $X$ is geometrically connected since it has a $k$-rational point ($0$ and $1$ are both rational points).  Let $Y$ be the base-change of $X$ to an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$.  Note that $Y_{red}$ is a subring of $Y$ (the ring operations $Y\times Y\to Y$ restrict to morphisms $Y_{red}\times Y_{red}\to Y_{red}$ since $Y_{red}\times Y_{red}$ is reduced).  Since $Y$ is connected, so is $Y_{red}$, and it follows that $Y_{red}$ is irreducible (since its additive group structure makes it homogeneous).  If we show that $0=1$ in $Y_{red}$, that will imply $0=1$ in $Y$, and so $0=1$ in $X$ as well so $X$ is the trivial ring variety.

The upshot of all of this is that $Y_{red}$ is a proper ring variety over $\overline{k}$ and it suffices to show that $Y_{red}$ is trivial.  In other words, we may replace $X$ with $Y_{red}$ and assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Now consider the morphism $f:X\times X\to X\times X$ given by $f(x,y)=(xy,y)$.  Since we are assuming $k$ is algebraically closed, $X\times X$ is irreducible.  Note that the fiber of $f$ over $(1,1)$ is just $\{(1,1)\}$.  It follows that the generic nonempty fiber of $f$ is $0$-dimensional and so the image of $f$ has the same dimension as $X\times X$.  Since $X\times X$ is proper the image of $f$ is closed and since $X\times X$ is irreducible the image is dense, and so $f$ is surjective.  In particular, there exist $x,y\in X$ such that $f(x,y)=(1,0)$.  This implies $y=0$ and so $1=xy=0$.  Thus $0=1$ in $X$ and $X$ is the trivial ring variety.

(This argument does not use the full ring structure of $X$, but merely uses the fact that $X$ has a multiplication operation with an element $1$ such that $x1=x$ for all $x$ and an element $0$ such that $x0=0$ for all $x$.)